# Python data type apparently changes from "int" to "complex" between lines

Tags: python, types, while-loop, typeerror

I'm trying to list all numbers between 0 and 500 that can be reached by summing 25 and 40.

This shows my problem:

```
j = 1
i = 5

if type(i) == type(500):
    print("You're good to go!")
else:
    print("No dice.")

while i <= 500:
    j += 1
    i = 5j
```

```
You're good to go!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lyndon (default)/Desktop/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    while i <= 500:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'int'
```

I'm using IDLE (64-bit) for Python 3.8.1 on Windows 10 Professional. I originally started with i and j at 0, but changed them to see whether that would solve the problem. (It didn't, obviously.)

Comment: `5j` is a complex number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ( if this is what you are trying to ):

```
j = 1
i = 5

if type(i) == type(500):
    print("You're good to go!")
else:
    print("No dice.")

while i <= 500:
    j += 1
    i = 5*j
```

In python, complex numbers are of the form `a + bj`. So when you give `5j`, it is now a complex number.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `i = 5j` expression makes `i` a complex number, which is supported by default in Python.
So instead use `i = 5 * j`